# setreuid call fails to re-establish process permissions 

Tags: c, linux, permissions, root, setuid

I am a bit confused with setreuid.

Scenario: A process runs as normal user (id: cateof) but for a very short fraction of time needs to be run as root. I have to elevate permissions to root from cateof and then back to normal user. My first thought was that nesting my "root call" between a setreuid(0, 0); and a setreuid(ruid, euid); would be enough, but I was wrong. The only way to go back to normal user is to call setreuid(ruid, euid) twice in a raw after the "root call".

Here is the code:

```
int main(...) {
    //check the permission, that the program is setuid
    //become normal user 
    ruid = getuid ();
    euid = geteuid ();
    setreuid(ruid, euid); 
    ...
    setreuid(0, 0);
    root_action();
    setreuid(ruid, euid); //undo root #1
    setreuid(geteuid(), getuid()); //undo root#2
```

If I don't call the **setreuid(geteuid(), getuid())** at the last line the process keeps running as root. Why do I need to call it twice???

Comment: what's the return code of `setreuid`? and `errno` value?

Comment: @Aif all setreuid calls return 0 (success)

Comment: can you clarify how a normal user can do **setreuid(0, 0);**?

Comment: @tuxuday I edited my question. the program tries to unset root privileges at the beginning of main function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're first call to setreuid is actually a no-op - it does not drop privileges, you are essentially saying set my real uid to my `getuid` and my effective uid to my `geteuid`, which in the case of a setuid app is the same as you obtained.

At the start of a setuid `root` program run as user `bob`, then `getuid() == bob`, `geteuid() == root`

If you want to drop privileges, then you should probably have called:

```
setreuid(euid, ruid);
```

Thad would have set the effective uid to `bob` and the real uid to `rood`. Everything done after that point will be *as if by the unprivileged user bob*, understanding that you have not completely dropped the ability to switch back to `root` privileges at this point, because you have not wiped out the saved-user-id information.

Obtaining root privileges would be done by:

```
setreuid(ruid, euid);
```

Similarly, at the end, when you are re-dropping privileges, you need to do the same:

```
setreuid(euid, ruid);
```

i.e. set the effective uid to the id `bob`. the [answer here][1] is a similar situation, which explains the details a little more concisely.

Generally, when checking this information, a little printerhelper like:

```
void printids(char *header) {
    uid_t ruid, euid, saveduid;
    getresuid(&ruid, &euid, &saveduid);
    printf("%s ruid=%d euid=%d saveduid=%d\n", header, ruid, euid, saveduid);
}
```

assists in determining the privileges/uid information at all the steps.

it would be a little simpler to just use `seteuid()` for the temporary changing of the privileges, rather than the little more heavy handed `setreuid()`. You can also use the `setresuid()` call to be more explicit on the setting of the real, effective and saved userid values.

Saving and dropping privileges:

```
setresuid(ruid, ruid, euid);
```

Re-obtaining root privileges:

```
setresuid(euid, euid, -1);
```

Dropping back to non-root privileges:

```
setresuid(ruid, ruid, -1);
```

i.e. we let the saved user-id keep the root information, and manipulate the `realuid` and `euid` values toggling between root/non-root